# Execute request depending on pass/fail status of other request in same script

Tags: jmeter-5.0

Consider there are 4 HTTP request in script.
I want to execute 4th request only if 1st request is success. 
Please help how can i achieve this in JMeter.

Comment: Did my answer helped? do you need more info?

Answer (score 0):

Add a child [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) for first request:

```
vars.putObject("isSuccess", prev.isSuccessful() );
```

Add a parent `If Controller` to 4th request and check the saved variable:

```
${isSuccess}
```